# RTF - How to embed font from a file?

Tags: rtf, font-embedding

According to the rtf specs, you can embed a font in an rtf file using the \fontemb and \fontfile control words. Can someone give me a working example of that?
I'd like the rtf file to use the font that's located in a separate file (i.e. .ttf file)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980432/embedded-fonts-in-rtf
I added my solution here.