# Embedded fonts in RTF

Tags: ms-word, rtf, font-embedding, wordperfect

According to the rtf specs, we can embed a font in an rtf file using the \fontemb and \fontfile control words. Can someone give me a working example of that? I'd like the rtf file to use the font that's located in a separate file (i.e. .ttf file)

Answer (score 1):

You should use TTEmbedFont function to create embedded font data. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145145(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145145%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Like this.

```
    //WRITEEMBEDPROC
    unsigned long WriteEmbedProc(void *lpvWriteStream, const void *lpvBuffer, const unsigned long cbBuffer)
    {
        BYTE *rgByte = new BYTE[cbBuffer];
        memcpy(rgByte, lpvBuffer, cbBuffer);

        //stream to store your font information
        std::ofstream *ofs = static_cast<std::ofstream*>(lpvWriteStream);

        //convert binary data to hexadeciaml, that rtf uses
        std::string byte_string = BinToHex(rgByte, cbBuffer);

        //Write formated data to your file (stream)
        for (int i = 0; i < byte_string.size(); ++i)
        {   
            *ofs << byte_string[i];
            if((i + 1) % 128 == 0)
            {
                *ofs << "\n";
            }
        }

        delete rgByte;
        return cbBuffer;
    }

   void EmbedFontWrap(HDC hdc)
   {
    ULONG ulPrivStatus = 0;
    ULONG ulStatus = 0;
    std::ofstream *lpvWriteStream = new std::ofstream("D:\\out.txt", std::ios::binary);
    USHORT *pusCharCodeSet;
    USHORT usCharCodeCount;
    USHORT usLanguage;
    LONG ret = TTEmbedFont(
        hdc,
        TTEMBED_RAW | TTEMBED_EMBEDEUDC,
        CHARSET_UNICODE,
        &ulPrivStatus,
        &ulStatus,
        WriteEmbedProc,
        lpvWriteStream,
        nullptr,
        0,
        0,
        nullptr);
    lpvWriteStream->close();
    delete lpvWriteStream;
}
```

Font you want to embed should be set as current for you device context by SelectObject function.